# java.util.NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, sql, tomcat6

I am getting the following error while trying to execute my code

```
--- Check the Segment.getVirtualSegmentId.  
--- Check the SQL statement.  
--- Cause: java.util.NoSuchElementException
```

(but the method does exist and the query runs correctly in SQL Developer), redeploy the tomcat did the trick but again after sometime without changing anything in the code, the above error has been thrown.

The code which is throwing the error is

```sql
<select id="getVirtualSegmentId" resultClass="java.lang.String" >
  select max(substr(attr_value,instr(attr_value, '-')+1))
  from circ_inst inner join circ_attr_settings
     on circ_inst.circ_inst_id=circ_attr_settings.circ_inst_id and val_attr_inst_id=1045
  where REGEXP_LIKE (circ_attr_settings.attr_value, 'LAYER 2 SWITCH-[0-9]+$') or
      REGEXP_LIKE (circ_attr_settings.attr_value, 'IPANEMA-[0-9]+$') or
      REGEXP_LIKE (circ_attr_settings.attr_value, 'FIREWALL-[0-9]+$')
</select>
```

Comment: Can you show us the code that produces the problem?

Comment: Please edit that into your answer and format it properly. It is entirely illegible where it is.

Comment: above code is throwing the error, the sql runs correctly in sql developer and I am not sure whether it has to do with tomcat deployment or a change to the query ?(but the same code worked yesterday)

Comment: the code has been updated in the question

Answer (score 0):

I could avoid the exception by removing the "+$" from the query. Thanks everyone for the responses